# Getting minimum and maximum value from a table - SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table called country with a column called population. I need to get a table with only the highest and lowest population country. I have tried:

```
select max(population) from country;  

select min(population) from country;
```

but I can't figure out how to combine these queries into only one query.

Best wishes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select min(population), max(population) from country;
```

Will get you a result with two columns, the first holding the minimum population and the second the maximum population.

That only returns the populations though. If what you need is a query that will return the two countries, embedded queries would do :

```
select * from country where population=(select min(population) from country) or population=(select max(population) from country);
```

Comment: When i try your second query i get the error "aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE", any tips?

Comment: "Don't trust someone who hasn't wrote any SQL in some time" would be a good tip I guess :-/ The error message means you can't use functions that work on the whole table in the `where` clause, which I had forgotten ; let me check how to go around that

Comment: I've fixed my query, but I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select country,min(population) from country
group by 1
Union
select country,max(population) from country
group by 1
order by 1;
```